# What would cause an HTML5 canvas toBlob to create an incomplete image?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-canvas, chromium, form-data

I have the following javascript produce images from a canvas and upload them to a server.

```
var can = document.createElement('canvas');
can.width = 600;
can.height = 600;
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
ctx.fillText("Julia", can.width/2, can.height/2);
can.toBlob(uploadImage, "image/jpg", 0.9);

function uploadImage(jpeg) {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('image', jpeg, 'image.jpg');
  ...
}
```

[image]

Every so often, the result looks like the above, only partially drawn. Multiple canvases are processed and uploaded serially, only moving on in the completion of the ajax (in the ... part), so only one at a time.

Have you seen this happen? If so, where in this process should I debug further? Maybe a setting or something in the context object?

**Edit**

The upload is an ajax post with a promise resolved only on the success branch. It actually uses angular's $http service:

```
$http({method: 'POST', url: '...', data: data}).then(function(response) {
    // callback that processes and uploads the next image
});
```

Comment: To me it looks like the image upload was interrupted and you only have part of the image. I have never seen toBlob or toDataURL do that to an image, but I have seen plenty of incomplete jpegs that look like that when down & uploaded due to connection failure

Comment: Can you show the code that does the upload?

Comment: So is it possible for the javascript to see the success path if the server doesn't read the entire request?...I think not but maybe this is an angular question. Maybe a simple buffering issue on the server...maybe I can pass the blob size as another form parameter and check it against the received file size on the server.

Comment: @RyanCalhoun Yes, that sounds like a good idea. You definitely need to put more logging to find out where the corruption happens, if you cannot easily reproduce

Comment: hi @RyanCalhoun did you check my answer, did it helped

Answer (score 2):

We were facing with similar except part with canvas. You can debug it simply.

1. Print given blob to page as img src to make sure that file was created properly. Print also blob size.
2. Open browser's developer tools -> Network -> Filter XHR and start uploading
3. Assign finished(status 200) ajax request and look at Request Headers -> Content-Length. If this number is equal to blob size on page, it was uploaded properly and find issue on server side. Else check ajax call.
4. Make sure that server has set max client request size appropriate to your usecase. For example nginx has default value 1M.

TIP: set Content-Type by blob.type in $http headers. Default value for POST is application/json.

Comment: Or even better, don't do via devtools, but let the server respond with the size of the uploaded file and compare on the client to check whether it went well.

Comment: What was the issue you had, did you figure it out? Was the client not sending the image or was the server not receiving it?

Comment: Yea. We did. But I used https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload. It provides few useful features for media files like resizing, progress and so on.. We worked also with large video files chunked to 10M parts so first time it was nginx's max_request_body_size cutting our request. Then one bug in logic of backend reader(python). But we implemented also things like pause and resume so it was little different case. Debug steps above should be generic for all kinds of these issues + logging on both sides always shows whats wrong..

Answer (score 0):

try to rearrange your logic a little,, you are getting racing condition with uploading process and when the image is created, they have to be callback in callback sorta ..

```
// ...
ctx.fillText("Julia", can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
can.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var newImg = document.createElement('img'),
        url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    newImg.onload = function() {
        // no longer need to read the blob so it's revoked
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        newImg.src = url;
        // we have image out of canvas and now do the upload of newImg
        // $http || $.ajax call goes here
    };
});
```

of if you want to submit image data URL try something like,,

```
// ...
ctx.fillText("Julia", can.width / 2, can.height / 2);
can.toBlob(function(blob) {
    var reader = new window.FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
    reader.onloadend = function() {
                base64data = reader.result;
        // we have image in base64 and now do the upload of base64data
        // $http || $.ajax call goes here
    }
});
```

hth, k